# How to Pass variable from shell to Java code?

Tags: java, shell

I have a Java code which needs a proxy value to run. That proxy value changes with the environment. So I'd like to make it as variable which I can pass from shell, so the java code remains environment agnostic. Here's the snippet of the java code. As you can see I am trying to make the **web-proxyapp.xxxxx-dns.com** and **port number** as a variable that I can pass from shell or the Java code picks it up automatically from Linux environment variables.

```
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import step_definitions.StepDefinitions;

private Response getCyaraResponse(String cyaraService) {
    try {
        RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation();
        RestAssured.proxy("web-proxyapp.xxxxx-dns.com", 3128);          
        log.debug("Get URL: " + baseUrl + accountNum + cyaraService);
        Response actualResponse = given().headers("Authorization", keyToken)
                .get(baseUrl + accountNum + cyaraService);
        return actualResponse;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am not an expert in Java so would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, at least as stated, this is a terrible idea and you need to re-think your whole approach.  Second, you can pass information on the command line or as an environment variable.  But a far better way is to manage this information externally, with a standard tool, like using an XML configuration file or some form of JNDI.

Comment: Either use environment variables (`System.getEnv()`), properties (passed with `-Dname=value` and obtained using `System.getProperty()` or command line arguments (`args` parameter of `main`.

Comment: @markspace It's not a "terrible" idea at all; environment variables are very often used to maintain environment-specific information, and fit nicely into containerized deployment mechanisms, and are trivially cross-platform.

Comment: I disagree with that a lot.  I've had large problems with left-over environment variables causing problems (often silently) with installations.  I think they're pernicious and should be deprecated.  Command line is better.  XML or managed tool is better still. @DaveNewton

Comment: @markspace *shrug* Little else makes sense in a Helm-managed cross-ecosystem environment. Poor env management is orthogonal. Silent failure is a dev problem.